# Make "crlFile" property in tomcat dynamic

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, certificate-revocation

For performing client certificate authentication(SSL) at server side for revocation, we can add property crlFile in tomcat connector. But this process is static means if the crlFile in that location updates, tomcat wont pick new CRLs it still binded to the old CRL file. Tomcat needs restart to pick the new changes in CRL file.

I have two questions here,

1) How to make the above process dynamic( If CRL file in that path is updated, pick the changes without any restarting) ?

2) How to get updated CRL files from CA timely and where to configure CDP(CRL distribution point) in tomcat so that if CA updates CRL files it downloads the file( which have some expiry time) to local machine(server) ?